# Upgrading my AMD Processor - is a higher bus speed safe?

Tags: cpu

I'm trying to upgrade my AMD processor to a better model, my motherboard specs say the processor has to be 89 watts or less and supports a bus speed of up to 2000 Mhz. The processors I'm looking at ARE 89 watts but the bus speed range anywhere from 2200-3000. My question is, **is it safe to have a processor with a higher bus speed than my motherboard specs say?** If not, then I won't have any other choice but to get a better motherboard, which I really don't want to do.

Comment: Just check the motherboard compatibility table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All modern AMD processors use [HyperTransport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperTransport).  The processor will simply operate at a slower bus speed. [HyperTransport is backwards compatible](http://www.hypertransport.org/default.cfm?page=FAQs#faq9) and will properly handle devices with different speeds.  From page 6 of http://www.hypertransport.org/docs/wp/HT_System_Design.pdf:

> When devices supporting different clock speed and link widths are connected together, the HyperTransport technology protocol layer ensures the bus works correctly without the need for special I/O drivers.

I don't see why installing such a processor would be unsafe, as long as the processor and motherboard sockets are compatible.

Comment: For one thing, if the motherboard cannot provide the supply voltage the CPU needs.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The supply voltage is always the same for a given socket.  Wattage is a more important factor, and the processor to be selected will be within the 89-watt limit.

Comment: Do you have a citation that says that AMD doesn't add new VID entries when they release new CPUs? I know Intel does. And I can't find any reference that documents AMD's policy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this type of compatibility problem--can you explain it to me?

Comment: When AMD or Intel release new CPUs, they often run at different voltage levels from previous CPUs. They often also have different requirements for things like how the voltage level is changed (how quickly, how much current must be supplied while it's changing, and so on). Motherboard VRMs must meet these new requirements to support new CPUs. A motherboard can't be designed to meet VRM requirements that don't exist at the time the motherboard is made, so if a CPU has new VID/VRM requirements, a motherboard can't support it without hardware changes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How much performance would be affected if I get a 2400Mhz CPU and my board only support 2000Mhz? Would it be that noticeable?

Comment: Memory-intensive operations may be slightly slower due to reduced CPU-memory transfer rate, but otherwise the impact is limited.

Comment: How much might it affect a game? Say Diablo 3? My current processor is 2000Mhz but D3 requires 2200? I guess would it recognize the processor meets the requirements?

Comment: The requirement is for the processor clock rate, not the bus speed.  Don't confuse the clock rate for the bus speed.  The processor will operate at its specified clock rate, such as 2.4 GHz.  The bus speed is not a key requirement for most games.